# xlsxwriter charts don't show up?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, xlsxwriter

I am using xlsxwriter to add charts to different worksheets in ipython and everything works, except my graphs are never showing up in the worksheets. There are no error messages.

When I tested the code from the documentation I also get a empty excel workbook.
I've tried it with xlsxwriter.Workbook and pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') but with both the workbook generates but no graphs are added.

How can I make the graphs show up?

Code from the documentation:
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_charts.html

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_line.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add the worksheet data to be plotted.
data = [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50]
worksheet.write_column('A1', data)

# Create a new chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Add a series to the chart.
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6'})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('C1', chart)

workbook.close()
```

The results for 
print(xlsxwriter.**version**)

0.5.7

print(zipfile.ZipFile("chart_line.xlsx").namelist())

['xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml', 'xl/workbook.xml', 'xl/charts/chart1.xml', 'xl/drawings/drawing1.xml', 'docProps/app.xml', 'docProps/core.xml', '[Content_Types].xml', 'xl/styles.xml', 'xl/theme/theme1.xml', '_rels/.rels', 'xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels', 'xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels', 'xl/drawings/_rels/drawing1.xml.rels']

Comment: I open the file in Excel (2013) and its blank. Its the same for my cowoker

Comment: just installed Libre and the graph also does not show up...

Comment: Okay, thanks for the edits. You're using an older version (I'm running 0.7.2) but I found 0.5.5 floating around and it worked for me too (I guess there could be a bug introduced between 0.5.5 and 0.5.7 and then fixed, but that seems unlikely.)  Those are the right files the xlsx should contain.  I'd suggest some weird Excel thing, but that wouldn't explain why you couldn't see it in libreoffice either.  So I'm afraid I'm stumped. :-/

Answer (score 1):

There haven't been any reported issues of charts not displaying in Excel in any version of XlsxWriter that supported charts.

There are also almost 300 chart comparison tests in the XlsxWriter codebase that test the charts that it produces byte for byte against files produces by Excel. These are all passing.

Also, the output from zipfile in your post clearly shows the chart elements are there. If they were present but incorrect Excel would complain when it loaded the file.

And the code that you link to has a screenshot of the output that clearly shows a chart.

I also ran the code and see the chart in 3 versions of Excel and 1 version of LibreOffice.

So you need to go back and verify your results. If you think there is an issue then create a small working program that demonstrates it and submit a bug report.